# Module not found (MODULE_NOT_FOUND) on nest.js code base

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nestjs

I have a code base which is working perfectly fine on a Windows box on node v10.16.3 but when I try to install the same code base on a CentOS Linux box with node v.12.16.3, I get the following error. Not sure what the issue could be.

```
# npm start

> nest start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
Require stack:
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/schematics/schematic.option.js
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/schematics/index.js
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/generate.action.js
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/index.js
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/command.loader.js
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/index.js
  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/schematics/schematic.option.js:3:16)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/schematics/schematic.option.js',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/schematics/index.js',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/generate.action.js',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/index.js',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/command.loader.js',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/index.js',
  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-22T14_14_24_709Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you try do `install` before using `start` ? Have you made sure you use same `package  manager`(npm/yarn) consistently. Have you made sure you have the same versions of `node/npm` ?

Comment: I did do an install before start. I use npm in both places. The npm version is different though. My node/npm versions are different as I stated in my post but I am using a higher version in Linux.

Comment: Try to run `npm install @angular-devkit/core` and see if it works.

Comment: That is one of the first things I tried. Same error.That npm install on angular-devkit worked fine though.

Comment: Have you tried `yarn global add @nestjs/cli` or `npm i g @nestjs/cli`? If not, try that and report back, please.

Comment: Do you have the package-lock.json that was working on the first environment? If so try to use npm ci

Comment: remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, then run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 6):

Delete the dist folder and again run `yarn start`, `npm start`, `yarn start:dev` or `npm run start:dev` to rebuild the dist folder. In addition `yarn prebuild` or `npm run prebuild` does the same thing using `rimraf`

The problem occurs when you change a name and the `tsc` does not change it in dist and transpiled `.js` files, so it cannot find the module

I think to the best of my knowledge, nestjs or tsc does that to make the transpilation faster

Answer (score 3):

Nothing else worked for me but the following did:

```bash
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

i'm not completely sure if there is any adverse impact to this though

Answer (score -1):

most important where you started node js the dist/ or / build folder has a worng path which we import or required so for
NPM : npm install --save-dev webpack
and for yarn add webpack this one packeg will slove your problem